# Object not disposed due to System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ObservableCollection of `Snapshot` Objects, bound to the ItemsSource of a ListBox.
If a new `Snapshot` Object is pushed into the collection and the collection already contains 3 Elements the last `Snapshot` Object is removed. However the removed object is never collected by the GC. To verify this I called `GC.Collect()` after removing an Object from the collection and profiled my Application with YourKit Profiler. After creating 6 `Snapshot` Objects YourKit Profiler made a Memory Snapshot. All 6 `Snapshot` Objects were still alive although only 3 were referenced by the Collection. The other 3 were referenced by System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry.

When the collection is not bound to the ItemsSource of the ListBox, the `Snapshot` Objects are collected as expected.

How can i get rid of the reference from System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry?

```
public class Snapshot
{
    public BitmapImage PreviewImage { get; set; } // Freezed BitmapImage
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LastCapturedPictures}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCapturedPicture}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 Margin="0,2,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="5,0,5,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=PreviewImage}" Width="130" Height="100"
                               Margin="0,0,0,2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Image.BitmapEffect>
                                <DropShadowBitmapEffect/>
                            </Image.BitmapEffect>
                        </Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="0,2,0,0" Grid.Row="1"
                                   TextAlignment="Left"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably far to late, but I think your issue isn't with EffectiveValueEntry, but with your Snapshot class.

If you want to bind to this class, you should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

I don't know the inner workings of WPF fully, but when using memory profilers like ANTS, you can see a much different retention graph to your object.

For example, your Snapshot class will currently cause WPF to create ValueChanged event handlers for each property you are binding to in XAML via reflection and it is these that don't clean up properly. When you implement INotifyPropertyChanged, this doesn't happen and bindings clean themselves up property.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Unfortunately I can't verify your solution, since I no longer have access to the software.